Why I have SSL certificate issue with python 3.12.0 or lower but not with 3.13.1?
I can only install with pip install on the latest 3.13 version. The system version I use is 3.13 and since tensorflow requires version 3.9 - 3.12, so I need to install another version for the virtual environment with venv. However, the error below occurred and I can't install any packages using pip
(testenv) PS D:\Virtual Env\testenv\Scripts> python --version
Python 3.11.5
(testenv) PS D:\Virtual Env\testenv\Scripts> pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.2.1
setuptools 65.5.0
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping
(testenv) PS D:\Virtual Env\testenv\Scripts> pip install tensorflow
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/tensorflow/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping

I assumed it uses my certificate that act as self-signed certificate or untrusted by CA? I also have lower version of openSSL but I think it comes as built-in module.

Do you have some sort of proxy setup?

Have no proxy setup

There is an SSL intercepting proxy in the middle. At least that would explain the error message. You may not be aware of it, but it's there. You need to tell Python to trust the intercepting proxy's certificate. Perhaps consult the sysadmin for your network.

Try to run the pip with --isolated option. If it makes a difference, check the config files and env variables.
